# how to solve stack security problem assembly

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm a new assembly programmer and I wonder if there is a way to completely clean the stack 
(from all the function parameters and the function pointer ) 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**emu8086 emulates real mode.  There is no security**; all code runs with full privileges to take over the whole machine.  You have to trust your caller; your caller could have disassembled the machine code of your function and even modified it before calling.

But sure you *can* overwrite your args on the stack before returning.  In most calling conventions, the stack args are "owned" by the callee so they can use them as local vars anyway.

**However, no, it's impossible to jump somewhere without leaving the target address in memory or a register**.  `pop cx` / zero return address / `jmp cx` would let you emulate `ret` after overwriting the return address in memory, but then it would be in a register.

I guess maybe you could set `TF` (the single-step mode trap flag) in FLAGS and use a debug interrupt handler to do something (like zero a return address) before disabling TF again.  But the debug exception frame pushes the CS:IP which includes that return address, and returning from the debug exception with `iret` will

But keep in mind: **a return address is not valuable info**.  The code you're returning to could already find its own address with `call +0` ; `pop ax` just calling one of its own functions.

---

**On modern x86, there *are* ways to make protected enclaves.**  For example, [SGX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Guard_Extensions) is designed for that, and [SMM (System Management Mode)](https://wiki.osdev.org/System_Management_Mode) is also "outside" even a kernel.

Or in protected mode, you might have calls between different privilege domains.  Usually user-space calling into a kernel.  **You avoid info leaks there by having the kernel use a separate private kernel stack.**  Necessary for security in a multi-threaded system, otherwise another user-space thread modifies stack memory while the kernel is using it, taking control of a kernel return address.

To avoid info leaks on a system call; preserve all registers except ones that contain return value(s) or get zeroed.  That way you can't leave any kernel temporary data in registers.  And since you aren't using the user-space stack at all, that's not a problem.

Comment: @Bartosz Wójcik: re: your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24684603): my 2nd paragraph already points out that you can zero  your incoming stack args if you want to.  Your suggested method (looping on `and word ptr [sp],0`) isn't valid: SP can't be used in addressing mode, and you can't leave the return address below SP temporarily; it could be destroyed by an interrupt.

Comment: If you're using `and` instead of `mov` to save 1 byte of code-size to optimize for 8088, that's crazy: the 2-byte load part of AND will cost more than code-fetch for `mov [mem], imm16`.  Plus, if you care about code size and perf on 8088, you'd use SS:DI with `ss stosw`.  Or `rep ss stosw` if you don't have to deal with 8086's broken interrupt-resume of rep instructions with 2 prefixes.  Or loop on `mov [bp+si+2], si` : it doesn't have to be zero, it just has to be some uninteresting value, so you can avoid any immediate with mov instead of and. BTW your edit should have been a separate answer